# Region Geochart region America

Tags: google-maps

I am learning to use the google Geochart tools I want to recreate a map like this one:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/171U4NeI_49iacbhzlX0A8nT6aB9N4guc6VWsELmP6wI/pubchart?oid=1478243202&format=interactive

My code is this:

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['States', 'Number of killings'],
          ['California', 292],
          ['Texas', 143],
          ['Washington', 120]
      ]);

      var options = {
          region: 'US'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

I am able o see the map, but I dont see the state divisions nor the colour I am using http://jsfiddle.net, I am sure it is a very basic error but I cant find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `{resolution: provinces}`:

working code snippet:

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['map']
});

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['States', 'Number of killings'],
    ['California', 292],
    ['Texas', 143],
    ['Washington', 120]
  ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'US',
    resolution: 'provinces'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div>
  <div id="regions_div" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
```